# Multiple easyXDM in one page

Tags: javascript, easyxdm

I am trying to use two easyXDM sockets on a single parent page without success. Both the sockets connect to the same remote domain but different endpoints. The parent page has two divs `false_app_div` and `dummy_app_div`.The following shows the code snippets -

On the parent page I have two JS functions `activate_false_app()` and `activate_dummy_app()`.

```
window.loadScript = function(src, onload, onerror) {
   var head = document.getElementByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = src;
   if (script.readyState) {
      script.onreadystate = function() {
         var state = this.state;
         if (state === 'loaded' || state === 'complete') {
             script.onreadystate = null;
             onload();
         }
      };
   }
};
window.activate_false_app = function() {
   var exdm_url = 'http://localhost:8000/js/easyXDM/easyXDM.min.js';
   on_load_fn = function() {
      window.init_false_app_communication();
   };
   on_error_fn = function() {
      return false;
   };
   window.loadScript(exdm_url, on_load_fn, on_error_fn);
};
window.init_false_app_communication = function() {
   var false_app_socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
      remote : 'http://localhost:8000/false_app',
      swf : 'http://localhost:8000/js/easyXDM/easyXDM.swf',
      container : 'false_ap_div',
      onMessage : function(message, origin) {
         alert('false_app onMessage');
         alert(message);
      }
   });
};
window.activate_dummy_app = function() {
  var exdm_url = 'http://localhost:8000/js/easyXDM/easyXDM.min.js';
  on_load_fn = function() {
     window.init_dummy_app_communication();
  };
  on_error_fn = function() {
     return false;
  };
  window.loadScript(exdm_url, on_load_fn, on_error_fn);
};
window.init_dummy_app_communication = function() {
   var dummy_app_socket = new easyXDM.Socket({
       remote : 'http://localhost:8000/dummy_app',
       swf : 'http://localhost:8000/js/easyXDM/easyXDM.swf',
       container : 'dummy_app_div',
       onMessage : function(message, origin) {
           alert('dummy_app onMessage');
           alert(message);
       };
   });
};
```

If in the parent page, I call either `activate_dummy_app()` or `activate_false_app()`, it works - that is both work completely fine in isolation. But if I call both, then only one of them works and I get an error on the JS console, that something is undefined (which I could not find).

Also, I know that the problem has something to do with loading two easyXDMs because if I put `init_dummy_app_communication` in the `on_load_fn` of `activate_false_app()` (in addition to `init_false_app_communication` already present), then both works.

However, I cannot be sure that easyXDM is already loaded, so both `activate_false_app` and `activate_dummy_app` has to load easyXDM, so that they work in isolation as well as together. I tried working with `noConflict` function, but the documentation there is poor and ended up with nothing concrete there.

Has someone faced a similar problem or knows what I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

EasyXDM allows you to have multiple instances of it per site. You can do this using `noConflict`.

For example, if you're building JavaScript that will go on a site you do not control, you can always create an instance of EasyXDM and set it to whatever you want.

I do this for our JavaScript widgets ([the usage can be viewed here](https://github.com/HigherLogic/widgets/blob/master/js/hlwidgetcommon.js)).  Each script can then call `ns.NSEasyXDM` and have a reference to it without pummeling the easyXDM in the global namespace (since it likes to put itself on the `window`).

If you need to talk to multiple endpoints, you can send in a different `consumerRpcConfig` and `consumerJsonRpcConfig` as needed.

```
this.ns = this.ns || {};
(function(ns, window, document) {
    var base = this,
        consumerRpcConfig = {
            remote: document.location.protocol+ "//my.path.org/Scripts/easyXDM/cors/"
        },
        consumerJsonRpcConfig = {
            remote: {
                request: {}
            }
        },
        init = function(el, callback) {
            var easyXDMElement,
                scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
                scriptIdx;
            for (scriptIdx = 0; scriptIdx < scripts.length; scriptIdx = scriptIdx + 1) {
                if (scripts[scriptIdx].src === document.location.protocol + '//my.path.org/Scripts/EasyXDM/easyXDM.js') {
                    base.isEasyXDMPresent = true;
                }
            }
            if (!base.isEasyXDMPresent || ns.NSEasyXDM === undefined) { 
                easyXDMElement = document.createElement('script');
                easyXDMElement.type = 'text/javascript';
                easyXDMElement.src = document.location.protocol + '//my.path.org/Scripts/EasyXDM/easyXDM.js';
                el.parentNode.insertBefore(easyXDMElement, el);
            }
             easyXDMElement.onload = function () {
                 ns.NSEasyXDM = { easyXDM: window.easyXDM.noConflict("NSEasyXDM") };
                 callback();
             };

        }
    return ns;
}(this.ns, window, document));
```

To define multiple copies of EasyXDM as shown above, use the "noConflict", assign each instance to a variable; and then you can pass that around.

Answer (score -2):

in this page;
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/easyxdm/bOoznzUrkjE

it is mentioned as;

```
(function(){
    var easyXDM;
    // paste easyXDM's minified code here

    var rpc = easyXDM.Rpc(.....
    ...
})();
```